# JavaFX with high scaling screen size

Tags: javafx, scaling, scenebuilder, dpi

I have started to learn how to build JavaFX GUI app recently, and I have faced some problems with window scaling in JavaFX. When I set my Window scale to 125% my application seemed to be zoomed in even when I set the stage to show in fullscreen. However, when I set my Window scale back to 100%, the application is just show in the normal view. Please provide some solution on how can we make the application flexible to every DPI or screen scaling. Also, I have been using SceneBuilder and Intellij IDEA to create just only a Anchor Panel and a VBox with no important codes involed. I do not know much about JavaFX, and my English is far from perfect, so please ignor some stupid remarks that may have occured in this question.

100% Scaled Window

[image]

125% Scaled Window

[image]

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml")));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
    double dpi = screen.getDpi();
    double scaleX = screen.getOutputScaleX();
    double scaleY = screen.getOutputScaleY();

    System.out.println("DPI: " + dpi + " - scaleX: " + scaleX + " - scaleY: " + scaleY);

    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.setTitle("JavaFX_Practice");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

Comment: there have been recent (fx16 or fx17, don't remember exacty) bug fixes around DPI scaling ... check if this happens with th current fx17. Also: I don't see the difference between those two black-in-black images - you might consider to use screenshots that make the issue obvious :) And provide a [mcve] to reproduce it (that is either code a simple ui by hand or add the fxml)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. We can tell the differences between this two images by looking at bottom of the border of the pane on your left. The screen seemed to be zoomed in when I use 125% scale.

Answer (score 0):

I faced that issue too. I have not found a solution in javafx directly, but I found a trick for my users who uses 125% window scale on Windows.

```
1. Right button click on desktop -> Display settings
2. Set scale to 100%
3. Do not close the settings window
4. Open javafx app
5. Go back to the settings window
6. Set your scale back
7. Close the settings window
```

This way a user of your app will be able to keep using his prefered scale, but your javafx app will be rendered on 100% scale until closed.

Comment: This can be a good trick. I will follow your instruction. Thank you for your advices, and I will look for how can we fix them permanently.